# How can I save coins from all games played? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a game where a character runs and picks up coins. When he picks up the coins they increment. However, how do I make it so that all coins from past games are saved as well. Say if the player collected 50 coins last game and 40 coins this game, he would have 90 coins in total. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

NSUserDefaults is what you are looking for. It is used to store simple app data. [Here](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/objective-c-to-swift-guides/nsuserdefaults-swift/) is a tutorial. Its easy to use and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about **NSUserDefaults**. This is class is exactly what you need for your game and it is really simple to use.

```
// this how you save your coins
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setInteger(0, forKey: "coins") // instead of 0 put current value of your coins 

//here how you can get the value in viewDidLoad method or whatever
userDefaults.integerForKey("coins")
```